# What can cause a MacBook LCD screen to become almost completely white (not white screen of death)?

Tags: laptop, macbook, lcd

On my `MacBook Pro Retina 15'' (Mid 2015 - A1398)`, a "service" store replaced the battery and since then, the screen stopped working normally. It starts almost totally white (however brightness control works), but I still can see computer is working. But what is really weird is that if I leave it turned off for 1 or 2 weeks, then it will start normally, image is perfect, and after 10 or 15 seconds, it will turn to white again. Then shutdown/restart won't fix it.

I already tried to open it, disassemble the screen from the computer, disconnect the cable and clean the connectors with isopropyl alcohol, but this did not work. I looked for people having similar issues and it seems to narrow down to the LCD screen or the LVDS cable. Examples:

https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/55908/My+display+is+slowly+fading+to+white.+Why
https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/140485/Why+does+my+screen+turn+white

I ordered 2 new cables and am waiting for them to arrive to try to replace it. I am not replacing the screen, but it seems strange to me that after some time without being turned on the screen is perfect again for 10 - 15 seconds. The computer works on an external screen.

Is there a way to be sure it is the cable and not the screen before replacing it?

**Pictures**

[image: OK]

[image: KO after 10 seconds then like this for 1 - 2 weeks]

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to DIY this. They broke it, they can fix it. Take it back to the repairer.

Comment: @Tetsujin Not possible. A family member brought it to me when visiting. We don't live in the same country. Things don't work like that in the country she lives in unfortunately. The repairer refuses to admit they broke it and it is impossible for us to prove it. And it is also too late now, so I'll try to fix it myself to avoid wasting it.